# Checksums in REST API responses

Tags: php, api, rest

Is it a good idea to send a checksum with the content of the response? And if so, what is the most common way to calculate the checksum?

Example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2011 21:32:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

22 
{test:1}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying protocol for HTTP is TCP which already has a checksum mechanism, so I think it would be useless.

If you still need this kind of thing you could calculate a SHA1 signature of the body content and include it as a custom header in your response, something like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2011 21:32:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
X-Checksum: 40325305549f7a09edb51ff8df9528ffd8434ac6
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always use the `Content-MD5` header (see RFCs [2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.15) & [1864](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1864)).

Comment: _The Content-MD5 header field has been removed because it was inconsistently implemented with respect to partial responses_.
[RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231)

Answer (score 2):

For what? Basically TCP pretty much handles that for you (since it's supposed to be a reliable protocol), so a checksum is less necessary and arguably redundant.

However, if you were to insist on it, I'd simply add an X-Checksum HTTP header of some kind.