# Android: If I get HttpResponse status code 200, then there's no data lost?

Tags: java, android, apache, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a question about Android(Java) HttpRequest and HttpResponse.
I use Apache library.

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String str = "";
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(str);
    }
}
```

And the response content `response.getEntity().getContent()` size is about 500KB

**Can I say that if I get status code 200 and I can read the content until EOF (End Of File) then there's no data lost via network transportation?**

**Or I cannot make sure if there is data lost so I need a CheckSum mechanism to check?**

Thanks.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Well ... that should be the case, right? :) If you have read all the entity content without exception, you've got the complete, correct response body. No need to add your own checksum.

The only problem I can see, is HTTP/1.0 server or intermediaries. If they use TCP FIN to end a response, the response body might be terminated prematurely without client's knowledge.

I don't think we need to worry about HTTP/1.0 at this point of time. If you do, you can design your data format so that premature termination can be detected on the client side.

Comment: "If you have read all the entity content without exception, you've got the complete, correct response body. No need to add your own checksum"
I was wondering if there's any possibility that I've read all the entity content, but client don't know if it's complete. So my question is, if there's data lost, then will apache library throw exception ?

Comment: there shouldn't be problems. of course, it doesn't hurt if you add your own integrity check (assuming you control the server end too?)

Comment: You could do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541421/checksums-in-rest-api-responses and add a checksum into the header and ensure that the body matches the headers checksum. (That is if you control the server)